# Timer of "setInterval" is a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a bouncing ball animation. I want to have a form (num1 and num 2) that is supposed to substitute the variable "int1" or "int2" as the timer of "draw1" or "draw2". Loading the file and typing numbers to the textboxes, then submitting them did not change interval. I really need help on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>Follow the Bouncing Ball</title>
<script>
 var context;
 var x=50;
 var y=240;
 var dx=5;
 var dy=5;
 var int1=form.getElementById('num1').value;
 var int2=form.getElementById('num2').value;

 function init()
 {
  context=myCanvas.getContext('2d');
  setInterval(draw1,int1)
  setInterval(draw2,int2)
 }

 function draw1()
 {
  context.clearRect(0,0, 100,500);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
  context.arc(x,y,30,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  //Boundary Logic
if( y<35 || y>470) dy=-dy;

y+=dy

 }

 function draw2()
 {
  context.clearRect(100,0, 200,500);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
  context.arc(x+150,y,30,0,Math.PI*2,true); 
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  //Boundary Logic
if( y<30 || y>450) dy=-dy;

y+=dy

 }

function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

</script>

<body onLoad="init()">
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1300" height="500">
 </canvas>
 <form>
  <input type="number" id="num1" min="1" placeholder="Enter Number" autofocus required    onkeypress='validate(event)'/>
  <input type="number" id="num2" min="1" placeholder="Enter Number" required onkeypress='validate(event)'/>
  <input type="submit" value="Animate">

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just really can't seem to substitute "int1" or "int2" with the numbers typed in the forms.

Comment: Once the interval is started, the time it takes before it's called again is already passed in, and you can't change it.

The workaround is using a recursive timeOut instead

Answer (score 1):

These two lines:

```
 var int1=form.getElementById('num1').value;
 var int2=form.getElementById('num2').value;
```

are being executed before the DOM has loaded. You're almost certainly getting errors in the browser console for that reason.  Move those into the "init" function.

Once you do that, however, things *still* won't work, because you're starting the timers in response to the page load completing (the "load" event).  If you need somebody to type in the values, then that's obviously not going to work. The simplest thing to do instead is to add a "Start" button, and couple a "click" event on that to the "init" function. *edit* Oh, OK, you've already got an "Animate" button. That should be where you set up the "click" handler.

Finally, as others have noted, you need to interpret the values of the input fields as numbers.

Comment: I have already tried using "Animate" as a submit button or a button that executes "init ()" on click and changed the strings to var int=parseInt(document. getElementById("num1").value) but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` so you can make the 'wait' time variable. So, instead of doing this:

```
var waitTime = 1000;
setInterval(function(){
   //your logic here
}, waitTime);    //Here waitTime sticks with the initial value
```

You do:

```
var waitTime = 1000;    //This can change anytime
(function tick(){
    //your logic here
    setTimeout(tick, waitTime);   //Here waitTime can vary in any cycle
})();
```

The difference, is that with `setTimeout`, you can modify `waitTime` anytime and it will affect the next cycles. But with `setInterval`, the initial value will keep "forever"

Also, your timers should update when you click the button, so you should have:

```
var int1 = 1000, int2 = 1000;  //Just default values
var document.querySelector("form input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(){
    int1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    int2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value); 
    return false; //Prefents form from being submited (I think you need this)
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: The timer of setInterval is the speed that function draw1 and draw2 makes its process (Clear area, make circle, increase location), right? I'm still really new to this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The others telling you you should change a string into a number are true, but it does not solve your problem. You are thinking that somehow magically by doing `var int1=form.getElementById('num1').value` once at the beginning of the script the `int1` is bound to the value of `num1` field. Of course it is not the case. `var foo=bar` is as assignment and nothing more; `num1` is assigned an actual value at the time of assignment and the expression is forgotten.

Another magical thinking is when you think `setInterval(draw1,int1)` changes the interval instantly once `int1` changes value. No, `setInterval` is called with the actual value of `int1` at the time of call and it doesn't care where the value came from (google 'passing parameter by value' to learn about the principle in general).

What you need to do, is

- install submit handler to the form (google 'onsubmit' if you don't want to use jQuery, or use jQuery's `.on('submit', function () {...})`). Inside the handler,

  - stop the timers (`clearInterval(timer1); clearInterval(timer2);`) but that means you must save the results in `setInterval` calls into variables `timer1` and `timer2`;
  - and then reinstall new timers (also remembering them into `timer1` and `timer2` so they may be stopped on subsequent form submission).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parseInt` like so:

`int2=parseInt(form.getElementById('num2').value);`

Without `parseInt`, it thinks that int1 and int2 are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You get String in here:

```
form.getElementById('num1').value;
```

You should parse `string` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to change the interval of a timeout after creation.

I would just cancel and recreate the timeouts upon value change.